# Decomposition of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Consider $A$ a subalgebra of the algebra $\operatorname{End} V$ of endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that A is semisimple. Then we can decompose $V$ as
$$V = \bigoplus_{i} U_{i} \otimes \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(U_{i}, V)$$
where $A = \bigoplus_{i} \operatorname{End} U_{i}$.

How can I prove this decomposition? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $V$ is a $A$-module and $A = \bigoplus A_i$, what is the submodule $M_i$ where $A_i$ acts non-trivially ?